# getting the label value of a button in Gtk

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk

Am learning Gtk. I wanted to build a calculator, in which i want to display the number pressed , in the textbox. I have completed it, by calling different functions for different buttons clicked, and appending the value in the textbox with the value of the button pressed. Using python 2.7.3

Is there a way to obtain the label value of the button pressed so that i can use a single function instead of 10 functions from 0 to 9?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Button callbacks include the widget itself, and you can also pass data. See [here.](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-ButtonWidget.html)

Answer (score 1):

instead of reading the label of the `GtkButton`, which is pretty much error prone, you should associate the value represented by the button to the button instance itself, e.g.:

```
button = Gtk.Button(label='1')
button._value = 1
# add button to the container
button.connect('clicked', on_button_clicked)

button = Gtk.Button(label='2')
button._value = 2
# add button to the container
button.connect('clicked', on_button_clicked)
```

and then read the value from the button instance inside the signal handler, e.g.:

```
def on_button_clicked(button):
    print 'you pressed the button of value: %d' % (button._value)
```

`GtkWidget` instances in Python are Python object, and thus behave like any other Python object.